# How to fix Samet SmartSlide desk drawer slider?

Tags: repair, furniture

[image]Long story short, I yanked on a drawer too hard and it got displaced on the sliders, I ended up getting it off them completely, in the process some parts fell out and I believe the right slider is missing them now. Question is, how do I reassemble them back. I haven't been able to find any schematics online for those specific parts, only on how to install the sliders.

Pics of the sliders (right one is the damaged one) and the parts that I need to put back in:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've got something better than a schematics, you've got a left side that's working. Take it out of the cabinet and do a forensic study on it. You should be able to put the right side back together. Good luck.

Comment: I worry that without knowing how it's built ill break it too and then ill have two bad sliders.

Comment: blum and other slides are commonly stamped with model or manufacturer in the metal.  find the make/model and order a new set of slides.  or take it apart just take pictures as you remove each piece.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger All, I got from the stamps is what's in the name of the post, I'll add a pic.

Comment: Seems like they have pdfs online...  and you could order a new set if needed.  https://www.samet.com.tr/uploads/products/files/1423574418d169.pdf